# SSIS OnPostExecute event: How to see the execution result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2017

I log SQL task activity to my own table using OnPreExecute and OnPostExecute which works fine. Here is the OnPreExecute code:

```
declare @audit_key int = ?
declare @package_name varchar(100) = ?
declare @task_name varchar(100) = ?

insert into fct.audit_avetmiss_detail
           (audit_key
           ,package_name
           ,task_name
           ,processing_start
, running_flag
)
select @audit_key, @package_name, @task_name, getdate(),1
```

..and OnPostExecute

```
declare @audit_key int = ?
declare @package_name varchar(100) = ?
declare @task_name varchar(100) = ?
declare @rows_source int = ?
declare @rows_inserted int = ?
declare @rows_discarded int = ?
declare @rows_updated int = ?

update fct.audit_avetmiss_detail
set Processing_end= getdate()
, running_flag = 0
, rows_source = @rows_source 
, rows_inserted = @rows_inserted 
, rows_discarded = @rows_discarded
, rows_updated = @rows_updated
where audit_key=@audit_key 
 and Package_name=@package_name 
 and Task_name=@task_name
```

How to access the Execution result of 'Success' or 'Failure' in OnPostExecute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, You have to use System variables to get the execution result and the error occurred (if exists), but based on the official documentation `OnPostExecute` event handler does not have access to System Variables that return the Execution Result or Error Description.

> @[System::ExecutionStatus] : OnExecStatusChanged event handler
>
> @[System::ErrorCode] : OnError event handler

Maybe you should log error when they occured `OnError` event handler, then you will assume that the package is failed. And don't use the `OnPostExecute` to log the Package Success. Instead of that add the `Execute SQL Task` at the end of package control flow. Then if all component success it will be executed and audit the package success.

For more information refer to the following documentation:

- [System Variables for Event Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-variables?view=sql-server-2017#system-variables-for-event-handlers)